# how to center tabularx result in `figure` enviroment

Tags: floats, captions, tabularx

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    oneside,
%   fleqn,          % auskommentiert um equations zu zentrieren
    listof=totoc,
    headlines=2.1,
    headsepline,
    numbers=noenddot,
    hyphens,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{picture.PNG}
    \caption{My caption is here}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm} p{\textwidth}}
        $m$:& my explanation for this variable is quite long\\
        $y$:& here another
    \end{tabularx}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

In the real document i have a picture with many variable in it. To make it clear i want to explain them in some kind of list below the picture. I'd like to have this list centered.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: (i) your table columns is wider than text width and declared table width. is this intentional? (ii) in `tabularx` you should use at least one `X` column. please clarify.

Comment: in my document i used for the first column `p{2cm}` and for the second `p{\textwidth-2cm}`. Somehow in this example it didn't work so i just removed the 2cm out of the second mention. i didn't know about `x` columns yet

Comment: but i don't think this changes my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  table is perfectly centred under the figure if you use the correct parameters, as the first code below shows. However I suggest another approach: using the `measuredfigure` environment from package `threeparttable` your explanations will have the exact width of the figure. Also, I think a `description` environment, customised through `enumitem` will produce a better solution:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    oneside,
% fleqn, % auskommentiert um equations zu zentrieren
    listof=totoc,
    headlines=2.1,
    headsepline,
    numbers=noenddot,
    hyphens,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{picture.PNG}
    \caption{My caption is here}\medskip
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{2cm}|X|}
        $m$:& my explanation for this variable is quite long\\
        $y$:& here another
    \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{measuredfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{picture.PNG}
    \caption{My caption is here}\medskip
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=2cm, leftmargin=2cm, labelsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, font=\itshape]
        \item[$m$:] my explanation for this variable is very very very long
       \item[$y$:] here another
    \end{description}
\end{measuredfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

red line indicate text borders. i only change `p{\textwidth}` with `L` column type, which is derived from `X` type:

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    oneside,
%   fleqn,          % auskommentiert um equations zu zentrieren
    listof=totoc,
    headlines=2.1,
    headsepline,
    numbers=noenddot,
    hyphens,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{picture.PNG}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm} L}
        $m$:    & my explanation for this variable is quite long \dots my explanation for this variable is quite long\\
        $y$:    & here another
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{My caption is here}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[
    pdftex,
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    oneside,
%   fleqn,          % auskommentiert um equations zu zentrieren
    listof=totoc,
    headlines=2.1,
    headsepline,
    numbers=noenddot,
    hyphens,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm]{picture.PNG}

    \medskip\small
    \begin{tabularx}{10cm}{p{1cm} L} % <-- table has the same width as image
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Legend}} \\
        $m$:    & my explanation for this variable is quite long \dots my explanation for this variable is quite long \\
        $y$:    & here another
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{My caption is here}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]